# import sql dump with InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I import sql dump with InnoDB engine, I have some problem such as:

```
#1005 - Can't create table '.\db_name\table_name.frm' (errno: 121) .
```

When it uses the default Engine, it's run successfully.

How can I solve this?

---

Thank you all, but there aren't any duplicate/invalid foreign keys, also i have change 
SET foreign_key_checks = "0" to "1";
but no fine result
here my error code in phpMyAdmin

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `mb_comment` (
`content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`post_id` int( 11 ) default NULL ,
`user_id` varchar( 30 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci default NULL ,
`id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
KEY `FK_comment` ( `post_id` ) ,
KEY `FK_comment2` ( `user_id` ) ,
CONSTRAINT `FK_comment2` FOREIGN KEY ( `post_id` ) REFERENCES `mb_post` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
CONSTRAINT `FK_comment` FOREIGN KEY ( `user_id` ) REFERENCES `mb_user` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table '.\myblog_db\mb_comment.frm' (errno: 121)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a invalid foreign key constraint, e.g. a reference to a non-existing record or table.

The best thing to do is make sure you import a complete dump of the schema/tables, you can also attempt the import by disabling foreign key constraint checks:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

# IMPORT CODE GOES HERE

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

If the default engine is MyISAM then the foreign keys will be ignored as they're not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because duplicate name of foreign keys.Other engine then innodb does not have foreign keys reference integrity check.